# kendoMultiSelect and kendoGrid Row Addition

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I have a kendoGrid that adds a row each time an option is selected from a kendoDropDownList. However, the list must be multiselect, and so if the user selects more than 1 option from the kendoMultiSelect, I want those specific number of rows to be automatically added to the kendoGrid as well. I'm not sure if this is possible, but any insight would help. Thanks!

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example

Comment: You add a row by calling [grid.dataSource.add](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/add) and you can absolutely call it in a loop, for instance iterating over the results of [multiSelect.value()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/methods/value).

Answer (score 0):

[This might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067630/multiselect-list-in-kendo-grid-inline-editing)

Also everything is possible in Kendo you just need to search for the right key word